# In JavaScript, can I use a ternary expression without the else part?

Tags: javascript, control-flow

I am pretty new to JavaScript and I am trying to make a little control flow example but it doesn't want to work because of multiple errors.For example on line 5 it says unexpected token:

```js
let raceNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
let registeredEarly = true;
const runnerAge = 21;

!registeredEarly ? raceNumber += 1000;

if(runnerAge > 18){
 console.log('You will race at 11:00AM with the racenumber ' + raceNumber);
} else if(registeredEarly === true || runnerAge > 18){
 console.log('Yu will race at 11:00am and your racenumber is ' + racenumber);
} else if(runnerAge < 18 && !regiteredEarly){
 console.log('You will race at 12:30pm and your racenumber is ' + racenumber);
} else{
 console.log('Pls register at the desk.');
};
```

Please explain to me what you did and why, I want to learn as much as possible!

Comment: You're using a ternary operator but have no "else" case.

Comment: So what do i do cant i just leave the else? i dont need one @Li357

Comment: Add the errors you get. And read the [tour] and [help] some time; your questions show no real understanding of how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Why use a ternary operator if you don't need the else part ?

Answer (score 1):

It is expecting ":" after 1000, not ";"

```
 !registeredEarly ? raceNumber += 1000 : null ;
```

To answer your comment, no you can't skip the ":" (else), because the syntax requires it.